# PHP Form Validation in Page

Tags: php, forms, validation, csv, isset

I have successfully created a PHP form that submits the information into a comma separated `csv` file. However, I do not like how it is handling errors/invalid submissions.

I don't want it to reload the page, clearing the user-entered input fields if the user didn't enter one of the required fields.

Instead, I want to display the error message on the same page, without reloading the page, keeping all of the user's inputed text in tact.

I am not sure how to do this successfully. I do not mind if both *form.php* and *csv.php* are merged into one file, but am not sure, again, how to do this successfully.

1. What is the best way to do this (in one file or with two separate files e.g. *form.php* and *csv.php*)?
2. How do I do it?

Thanks!

*form.php*

```
<h3>INFORMATION</h3>
<h6>Items in red are required</h6>
  <form action="csv.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="input_required" name="firstname" size="24" maxlength="30" placeholder="First name"> <input type="text" name="initial" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Initial"> <input type="text" id="input_required" name="lastname" size="24" maxlength="40" placeholder="Last Name"></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="firm" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Firm or Business"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="address" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Street Address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" size="28" maxlength="30" placeholder="City"> <input type="text" id="input_required" name="state" size="4" maxlength="2" placeholder="State">  <input type="text" name="zip" size="8" maxlength="8" placeholder="Zip Code"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="input_required" name="phone" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Telephone"> <input type="text" name="fax" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Fax"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="cell" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Cell"> <input type="text" id="input_required" name="email" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="E-mail"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="website" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Website"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>EDUCATION</h3>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="university" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="College or University"> <input type="text" name="degree" size="28" maxlength="254" placeholder="Degree Received"> <input type="text" name="degreeyr" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="jurisdiction" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Jurisdiction where admitted to practice"> <input type="text" name="jurisdictionyr" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year">
        </tr>
    </table>                    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"> <input id="button" name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
    <?php
      include "csv.php";
    ?>
  </form>
  <p>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['status'])){
        $status = $_GET['status'];
          if($status == 1){
            ?> <h1 style="color:green"><?php echo "Thank you for submitting your information!";?></h1> <?php
          }else if($status == 0){
            ?> <h1 style="color:red"><?php echo "There was an error!";?></h1> <?php
        }
    }
  ?>
  </p>
```

*csv.php*

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// Fetch the variables from the form
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$initial = $_POST['initial'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$firm = $_POST['firm'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$university = $_POST['university'];
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
$degreeyr = $_POST['degreeyr'];
$jurisdiction = $_POST['jurisdiction'];
$jurisdictionyr = $_POST['jurisdictionyr'];

//validate
if($firstname != '' && $lastname != '' && $state != '' && $phone != '' && $email != '')
{

//Comma seperate variables in CSV format
$cvsData = $firstname . "," . $initial . "," . $lastname . "," . $firm . "," . $address . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $zip . "," . $phone . "," . $fax . "," . $cell . "," . $email . "," . $website . "," . $university . "," . $degree . "," . $degreeyr . "," . $jurisdiction . "," . $jurisdictionyr ."\n";

// Location and Name of CSV file
$fp = fopen("data.csv","a");

if($fp){

// Write the information to the CSV file
fwrite($fp,$cvsData);

// Close the CSV file
fclose($fp);
}
    header('Location: form.php?status=1');
}
else {
    header('Location: form?status=0');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You're going to need to learn a bit about AJAX. If you're having difficulty with ajax, post a more specific question about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

Add an onchange() event handler to each text input:

```
<h3>INFORMATION</h3>
<h6>Items in red are required</h6>
  <form action="csv.php" method="post">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="input_required" name="firstname" size="24" maxlength="30" placeholder="First name"  onchange=validate(1)" /> 
      <input type="text" name="initial" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Initial" /> 
      <input type="text" id="input_required" name="lastname" size="24" maxlength="40" placeholder="Last Name" onchange=validate(2)"  />
      </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="firm" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Firm or Business" onchange=validate(3)" /></td>    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="address" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Street Address" onchange=validate(4)"  /></td>    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" size="28" maxlength="30" placeholder="City" onchange=validate(5)"  /> 
      <input type="text" id="input_required" name="state" size="4" maxlength="2" placeholder="State" onchange=validate(6)"  />  
      <input type="text" name="zip" size="8" maxlength="8" placeholder="Zip Code" onchange=validate(7)"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="input_required" name="phone" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Telephone" onchange=validate(8)"  /> 
      <input type="text" name="fax" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Fax" onchange=validate(9)"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="cell" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="Cell" onchange=validate(10)"  /> 
      <input type="text" id="input_required" name="email" size="35" maxlength="254" placeholder="E-mail" onchange=validate(11)"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="website" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Website" onchange=validate(12)"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h3>EDUCATION</h3>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="university" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="College or University" onchange=validate(12)"  /> 
      <input type="text" name="degree" size="28" maxlength="254" placeholder="Degree Received" onchange=validate(13)"  /> 
      <input type="text" name="degreeyr" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year" onchange=validate(14)"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="jurisdiction" size="80" maxlength="254" placeholder="Jurisdiction where admitted to practice" onchange=validate(15)" /> 
      <input type="text" name="jurisdictionyr" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year" onchange=validate(16)" />
    </tr>
  </table>          
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"> 
  <input id="button" name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
  <?php
    include "csv.php";
  ?>
  </form>
```

**JavaScript Validation**

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function validate(id){
var txt = document.getElementById(id).value;
if(id == 1){

}
else if (id == 2){

}


//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

---

### AJAX

Or you can pass the info via AJAX to a PHP script to do the validation:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var id;
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
function validate(n){
id = n;
var txt = document.getElementById(id).value;
    xmlhttp=null;
    var Url="validate.php"
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (xmlhttp!=null){
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getResult;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", Url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    var post = 'id=' + id + '&txt=' + txt;
    xmlhttp.send(post);
  }else{
    alert("UNEXPECTED ERROR: XMLHttpRequest not supported");
  }
};
```

Post AJAX response:

```
function  getResult(){
  var retVals = '';
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
    if (xmlhttp.status==200){
      var retVal=xmlhttp.responseText;

      msg.innerHTML = retVal;

    }
    else{
      alert("UNEXPECTED AJAX ERROR: : " + xmlhttp.statusText + "HTTP Status: " + xmlhttp.status);
    }
  }
};

//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

**validate.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$id = $_POST['id'];
$txt = $_POST['txt'];

// do validation

echo "<p>This is the response</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Without page loading

1. You have to learn AJAX to help you on this for validation using PHP.
2. Validate using JavaScript like Misunderstood answer.

> With page loading

For avoiding user input data cleared after page loads : merge csv.php and form.php and edit your input tag like:

```
<input type="text" id="input_required" name="firstname" size="24"
maxlength="30" placeholder="First name" value="<?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>">
```